# Connecting a remote JMS client to GlassFish 3

Tags: glassfish, jms, remote-access

I am trying to connect to GlassFish 3's JMS service from a standalone remote client. However I am getting a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here's my setup so far:

- Glassfish 3 JMS Service in LOCAL mode (I am assuming that EMBEDED mode will not work in this case because it bypasses the network stack)
- JNDI properties are specified as follows:

  java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory
  java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming
  java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl
- gf-client-module.jar (in GLASSFISH_HOME/modules) added to the standalone application's classpath. Also tried adding other jars present in the modules directory (such as jms-core.jar), but still getting the same ClassNotFoundException.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I found a solution. See [here](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/connecting-remote-client-glassfish-jms-service?force=381) for details, but the short answer is that I needed to add two jars to the classpath: imqjmsra.jar and imqbroker.jar. These were available inside a rar called imqjmsra.rar which can be found under glassfish's mq directory. I had to extract the two jars from this rar!

Comment: Broken link for this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using all of the individual Glassfish jar files that you might need (such as gf-client-module.jar, imqjmsra.jar, and imqbroker.jar), the preferred method is to use the gf-client.jar file.  It can be found at $GLASSFISH_HOME/lib.

There is more information at http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#StandaloneRemoteEJB.  That document pertains to using EJBs in standalone clients, but the solution is the same for using JMS.

Answer (score 1):

This is the complete list of client jars for glassfish 3 :

```
auto-depends.jar
deployment-common.jar
glassfish-corba-internal-api.jar    
internal-api.jar
management-api.jar
bean-validator.jar
dol.jar
glassfish-corba-newtimer.jar        
javax.ejb.jar
orb-connector.jar
common-util.jar
ejb-container.jar
glassfish-corba-omgapi.jar      
javax.jms.jar
orb-iiop.jar
config-api.jar
ejb.security.jar
glassfish-corba-orb.jar
javax.resource.jar
security.jar
config-types.jar
glassfish-api.jar
glassfish-corba-orbgeneric.jar      
javax.servlet.jar
ssl-impl.jar
config.jar
glassfish-corba-asm.jar
glassfish-naming.jar
javax.transaction.jar
transaction-internal-api.jar
connectors-internal-api.jar     
glassfish-corba-codegen.jar     
gmbal.jar
jta.jar
container-common.jar
glassfish-corba-csiv2-idl.jar       
hk2-core.jar
kernel.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Ivan A Krizsan's notes for the EJB certification, and depending on the Glassfish version, this should be enough:

- GlassFish 3 (and GlassFish 4 too, I've just tested it): $GLASSFISH_HOME/lib/gf-client.jar
- GlassFish 2: $GLASSFISH_HOME/lib/appserv-rt.jar and $APS_HOME/lib/javaee.jar