# Unable to find JNDI resource for JMS Chat Application

Tags: java, jms, jndi, glassfish-3

I am trying to develop a JMS application that runs on Glassfish 3.
Eclipse Indigo is my IDE.
I have tried to run **[this example](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/jms_ch2/index.html?page=2)**. If you find it necessary, I will copy the code here.
I do not understand exactly what should I do with JNDI. I have created through the Admin Console the two needed resources with the exact specified names, but I get this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Orb initialization erorr
at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:180)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getORB(SerialContext.java:365)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProviderCacheKey(SerialContext.java:372)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getRemoteProvider(SerialContext.java:402)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:347)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:504)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at Chat.<init>(Chat.java:38)
at Chat.main(Chat.java:113)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:152)
... 9 more
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'TopicConnectionFactory' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Orb initialization erorr]]
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at Chat.<init>(Chat.java:38)
at Chat.main(Chat.java:113)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Orb initialization erorr]
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:352)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:504)
... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Orb initialization erorr
at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:180)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getORB(SerialContext.java:365)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProviderCacheKey(SerialContext.java:372)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getRemoteProvider(SerialContext.java:402)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:347)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:152)
... 9 more
```

From what I have read, on a server, the InitialContext should work automatically.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: referencing the example you linked above, with what have you replaced the line:

`// ... specify the JNDI properties specific to the vendor`?
since this is where you initialize the context used to lookup objects.

Comment: @AhmadSaleh I haven't replaced it with anything. I have read that `InitialContext jndi = new InitialContext();` should do, so `Properties env` is not used. I have not found any tutorials on `Properties` for `JNDI` and `Glassfish`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a JAR problem with my classpath. The needed JARs are the one specified in the question, and the other two in the accepted answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489937/connecting-a-remote-jms-client-to-glassfish-3)**, namely:`gf-client-module.jar`, `imqjmsra.jar` and `imqbroker.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

Upon constructing the `InitialContext` you need to provide some properties that describes how to access and get objects from the JNDI server.

Mainly you need to provide a property that marks the vendor's implementation and another that points to the data store location, and you may need to specify other security or vendor specific properties.

In your case (glassfish), I think the following properties needs to be set:

```
// the initial context factory, choosing the glassfish implementation
env.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial","com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
// glassfish's server location
env.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "<host name or IP>");
env.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "<port number>"); // default is 3700
```

Comment: It is not working. I get the same exception. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @Dragos I think your problem is in some missing glassfish jars, you need to add some jars to your client's classpath. These jars should be included in the glassfish installation (in a "lib" directory).
I'm not sure what are the needed jars, and you may want to add all the jars initially -to make sure that this is the problem- and then clean things up. This post might help http://blog.thejeearchitectcookbook.net/post/2011/01/30/Setting-minimal-client-for-Glassfish-3.0.1

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will helped you,my environment :
JEE6+glassfish3V

```
 private static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
 private static Queue queue;
 public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
      Connection connection = null;
      Session session = null;
      MessageConsumer consumer = null;
      TextMessage message = null;

      Properties env = new Properties();

      //glassfish3V
      env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://localhost:8080");
      InitialContext jndi = new InitialContext(env);
      connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) jndi.lookup("jms/ConnectionFactory");
      queue = (Queue) jndi.lookup("jms/Queue"); // put your Queue here


      try {
           connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
           session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
           consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
           connection.start();

           while (true) {
                Message m = consumer.receive(1);

                if (m != null) {
                     if (m instanceof TextMessage) {
                          message = (TextMessage) m;
                          System.out.println(
                                  "Reading message: " + message.getText());
                     } else {
                          break;
                     }
                }
           }
      } catch (JMSException e) {
           System.err.println("Exception occurred: " + e.toString());
      } finally {
           if (connection != null) {
                try {
                     connection.close();
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                }
           }
      }
 }
```