# Interrupting EJB lookup

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb

Is it possible to interrupt a hanging `InitialContext.lookup` call?

The reason why: I have an EJB jar deployed on a Glassfish server. When I try to do a remote EJB lookup from a client (started via java web start), the lookup hangs forever when the server is not reachable (e.g. Server down or client not connected to the internet). Therefore I need a possibility to interrupt the Thread that does the lookup, otherwise the Thread will run forever.

I tried setting `ORBTCPConnectTimeouts` but it seems to be ignored by the `InitialContext`.

**EDIT**

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
ctx.lookup("EJBName"); // Here it hangs when server not reachable
```

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience when the JNDI service is not available, the client gets an exception immediately, I mean that you don't need to set up a timeOut value to deal with this kind of situations. Are you sure that you are not getting an exception when the server is offline? May be you are not handling it correctly.

---

If you don't specify any JNDI properties, it will assume that the client is running in the same machine that the server.

When the client is remote, you need to indicate some properties to allow the client to connect to the JNDI server. The most intuitive properties that you need to indicate are IP and PORT. Otherwise, how can it to know the server location?

These properties are a list of key/value pairs which can be defined mainly in two different ways: using a jndi.properties file or directly in your client code using other signature: InitialContext(Hashtable environment) .

These JNDI properties are vendor dependent, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763960/accessing-a-stateless-ejb-from-another-instance-of-glassfish/10194057#10194057) provide an example.

You also need to add to the client's  classpath the file gf-client.jar.

You will notice that it is not necessary to setup a timeOut when the client is implemented correctly.

Comment: I updated my question. There is no exception thrown, it just hangs when doing the lookup. Maybe this is just the Glassfish implementation of the lookup that will hang until the JNDI service is reachable?

Comment: What are the JNDI properties used?

Comment: I don't specify any JNDI properties. I Tried to specify a value for `ORBTCPConnectTimeout` but it didn't work

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I should have mentioned that the client launched via java web start. Is it still needed to specify the JNDI properties when using java web start?

Comment: Yes it is needed.
Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087951/ejb-jndi-look-up-in-glassfish-server-only-in-java-web-start